# Java - adding new Object within an if() statement to a list declared outside if(){}

Tags: java, list, if-statement, arraylist, instantiation

I have this code where the ArrayList was instantiated outside any condition:

```
List<PatientDto> list = new ArrayList<PatientDto>();

for(Object o : ObjectList){
    if(true){
        PatientDto patient = new PatientDto(....);
        list.add(patient);
    }
}

PatientDto dto = list.get(0);
```

Will I still be able to retrieve the new PatientDto() as I access the list, given that it was instantiated within the if statements?

Comment: yes, you can get it from list object like list.get(index).

Comment: Yes you are. But why are you doing if(true) this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: May be OP just used to show that condition to demonstrate his problem. His actual question about the scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, ANS is right I am asking about the scope, I just used some sample class names and conditions

Comment: Why not try it before posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes

Patient is inside the scope of your `if` clause but it can be accessed outside the block if you have access to the reference for the same outside the `if` clause.

The list has stored a reference of your `patient` object which will be accessible whereever you can access the list. Hence, you can access your contained object by fetching it from the list.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept if it cleared your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you are inserting it in to the list, you can get it by using index. Or you can iterate after insertion of all the objects later.

for ex:

```
 PatientDto patient = list.get(index);
```

**update :**

```
PatientDto dto = list.get(0);
```

Yes, that gives the `0`th indexed `PatientDto` from the list, which whatever you put earlier in that place.   Since you adding new instances in the loop, they give you the same.

coming to the scope

```
for(Object o : ObjectList){
    if(true){
        PatientDto patient = new PatientDto(....);
        list.add(patient);
    }
}

System.out.println(patient); // err, I dont know what is patient
System.out.println(list.get(0)) // yay here is the patient, use it.
```